# Not able to create my first SOAP service in php

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to build my first SOAP web server but I failed. I tried several tutorials but none of them works.Below is what i have tried so far:

**Server script:**

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

function getProd($category) {
    if ($category == "books") {
        return join(",", array(
            "The WordPress Anthology",
            "PHP Master: Write Cutting Edge Code",
            "Build Your Own Website the Right Way"));
    }
    else {
            return "No products listed under that category";
    }
}

$server = new soap_server();
$server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
$server->register("getProd");
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

**Client script:**

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

$client = new nusoap_client("https://mydomain/soap_server.php");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $client->call("getProd", array("category" => "books"));

if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h2>Books</h2><pre>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}


echo '<h2> Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre></br>';
echo '<h2> Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre></br>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre></br>';
```

When I call my page `https://mydomain/soap_client.php` I get

**Fault**

```
Array
(
    [faultcode] => SOAP-ENV:Client
    [faultactor] => 
    [faultstring] => error in msg parsing:
xml was empty, didn't parse!
    [detail] => 
)
```

**Request**

```
POST /dss/soap_server.php HTTP/1.0
Host: mydomain
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 507

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns9471:getProd xmlns:ns9471="http://tempuri.org"><category xsi:type="xsd:string">books</category></ns9471:getProd></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 26 Aug 2018 07:49:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 684
Connection: keep-alive
X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">error in msg parsing:
xml was empty, didn&apos;t parse!</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I can also provide `htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES)` if needed.

could you please help me to find how to solve the issue?
Any help will be appreaciated.
Thanks.

Comment: When PHP 5 came, they also made a native implementation of a Soap server and client. They are probably more stable and has better performance (and proper documentation). See NuSoap as a fallback if you, for some reason, can't install the native soap extension.

Comment: NuSoap is a little bit "outdated". Better use the native SOAP extension or the zend-soap library. [Zend SOAP Tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/1a736eefabe893fa66e4befeb226dcc8)

Comment: Most of the "how to" hits from Google were based on nusoap, so I tried this one. I will test provided the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Magnus Eriksson already pointed out - i would use in any case the native built in PHP Implementation

In your case it looks pretty simple (i wrapped your function in a class called `Book`)

**Server**

```
try
{
    $objSoapServer = new SoapServer(null, ['uri' => 'http://localhost/soap/server.php']);
    $objSoapServer->setClass('Book');
    $objSoapServer->handle();
}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

class Book
{
    public function getBooks($category)
    {
        if ($category == "books") {
            return join(",", array(
                "The WordPress Anthology",
                "PHP Master: Write Cutting Edge Code",
                "Build Your Own Website the Right Way"));
        }
        else {
            return "No products listed under that category";
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, [
    'location' => "http://localhost/soap/server.php",
    'uri'      => "http://localhost/soap/server.php",
    'trace'    => 1 ]
);

echo $client->__soapCall("getBooks",["books"]);
```

> For more information take a look at the official documention
>
> - [Soap Server](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/class.soapserver.php)
> - [Soap Client](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php)